# Align both names and equations in the same line

Tags: math-mode, align, itemize

In Overleaf, I would like to show variable names with their equation behind them.

To do so, I have tried:

```
\begin{align}
      Entropy \quad  1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}log_{2}(p_{ij})}{log_{2}n}\\
      IDF \quad  log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}
      \\
      Normal\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}
      \\
      ProbIDF \quad log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
      \end{align}
```

Which leads to:

[image]

And, I have tried:

```
\begin{itemize}
      \item Entropy \quad \quad \(1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}log_{2}(p_{ij})}{log_{2}n}\)
      \\
      \item IDF \quad \quad \(log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\)
      \\
      \item Normal \quad \quad \(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\)
      \\
      \item ProbIDF \quad \quad \(log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}\)\\
  \end{itemize}
```

Which leads to:

[image]

In the latter case, the words are aligned vertically, but the equations are not. How can I vertically align both?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}% more generous margins
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[66]
\begin{align}
&\text{Entropy} && 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}\\
&\text{IDF}     && \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
&\text{Normal}  && \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
&\text{ProbIDF} && \log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[66]
\[
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Entropy} && 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}\\
&\text{IDF}     && \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
&\text{Normal}  && \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
&\text{ProbIDF} && \log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
\end{aligned}
\]
\lipsum*[66]
\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[5em][l]{Entropy} $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}\log_{2}(p_{ij})}{\log_{2}n}$
\item \makebox[5em][l]{IDF} $\displaystyle \log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}$
\item \makebox[5em][l]{Normal} $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}$
\item \makebox[5em][l]{ProbIDF} $\displaystyle \log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Random notes:

- the logarithm is a math operator, so use `\log`, not `log`
- words like "Entropy" are text, and you should type them as such

Answer (score 2):

You can use an invisble alignment using a `&` at the beginning of each line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
     &  Entropy &  1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}log_{2}(p_{ij})}{log_{2}n}\\
     &  IDF  &  log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
     &  Normal & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
     &  ProbIDF  & log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Or if you want the equations to be left-aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
     &  Entropy & & 1 + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_{ij}log_{2}(p_{ij})}{log_{2}n}\\
     &  IDF  & & log_{2} \frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}b(tf_{ij})}\\
     &  Normal & &\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N} tf_{ij}^{2}}}\\
     &  ProbIDF  & &log_{2} \frac{n - \sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} b(tf_{ij})}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

(Note the second `&` after the name)

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the syntax highlighting.

Comment: The names should probably be inside something like `\text{}`, or `\textit{}` if you want italics, so that the kerning is correct. Compare `$Normal$` and `$\textit{Normal}$`, the former has a larger space between the N and the o.

Comment: @Willoughby I agree, but I'd refer you to the superior answer by user campa.